# Docker build timestamps

Tags: docker, console, docker-multi-stage-build

Is it possible to get step timestamps in a console/log file while running docker build command?

```sh
Step 28/49 : RUN find dist -name "*.map" -delete 
 ---> Running in 5e1ee1063999 
Removing intermediate container 5e1ee1063999 
 ---> a02191df133c 
Step 29/49 : FROM dotnet-install AS web-build 
 ---> e0ecdc23b275 
Step 30/49 : COPY src src 
 ---> d33c7da41fb9
```

I would like to identify the slowest steps and I would expect something like:

```sh
2019-11-25T12:00:00Z : Step 28/49 : RUN find dist -name "*.map" -delete 
 ---> Running in 5e1ee1063999 
Removing intermediate container 5e1ee1063999 
 ---> a02191df133c 
2019-11-25T12:10:00Z : Step 29/49 : FROM dotnet-install AS web-build 
 ---> e0ecdc23b275 
2019-11-25T12:20:00Z : Step 30/49 : COPY src src 
 ---> d33c7da41fb9
```

Comment: Thanks for the link @BMitch! Let's close this.